# What is the common filler used in plastic injection moulding?

Tags: materials, chemical-engineering

What are the common filler materials used in PP, PE, LDPE, HDPE, and PVC-moulded materials?

To give a background - I own a limestone quarry and selling calcium carbonate in powder form. I want to make value added products from CaCO3, which I came across the filler master batches. But I am not sure what type of plastics use that. Answer to this will help me identify a particular sector and do targeted market analysis as I understand different end users require different grades of CaCO3 fillers.

Comment: Calcium carbonate for one, what is your motivation for this question?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons for adding filler material to polymers for casting or moulding, for  example :

- Improving tensile strength, impact toughness and crack resistance : here short strand fibres such as glass or carbon may give the best performance but any powder filler will help to some extent.
- To increase bulk : especially with more expensive reins for obvious reasons cheap and easily handled materials which don't much compromise mould-ability and mechanical properties are preferred eg fumed silca, calcium carbonate powder, talc etc
- To simulate other materials : especially metals and some types of stone by adding fine powder of the appropriate material.
- To reduce density : especially hollow glass beads
- To control opacity/UV resistance

Adding any inert filler will also tend to increase cure/demould  times and reduce the heat generated and associated problems in exothermic cure multi-part resin systems although this is obviously less of an issue for thermoplastics.